# How do you return each record in a table as a single concatenated string that contains at least 1 of 4 values for each record in a different table?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table with 92k records with only one column, containing notes about leads.

I have another table with 32k lead records with 3 phone columns and one email column among others.

I want to query the 92k records to see if they contain any of the numbers or emails, then concatenate all those records and set that concatenated string as the value of the Notes column of the 32k table.

I have created a spreadsheet that will work but it's been processing for hours and is only half way through. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzRR8.png)

```
=IFERROR(ifs(
not(isblank(H30627)),Join(char(10),QUERY(Tasks!A:A,"SELECT A Where A 
Contains '"&H30627&"'",0)),
not(isblank(F30627)),Join(char(10),QUERY(Tasks!A:A,"SELECT A Where A 
Contains '"&F30627&"'",0)),
not(isblank(E30627)),JOIN(char(10),QUERY(Tasks!A:A,"SELECT A Where A 
Contains '"&E30627&"'",0)),
not(isblank(D30627)),Join(char(10),QUERY(Tasks!A:A,"SELECT A Where A 
Contains '"&D30627&"'",0))),"")
```

I felt that Bigquery would save a lot of time but I am a SQL noob and this is returning a left outer join error without the STRING_AGG and 0 modified rows with it.

```
#standardSQL
UPDATE sfdc.workingFin
SET Notes = (SELECT STRING_AGG(string_field_0) from sfdc.tasks where 
string_field_0 LIKE (SELECT Email from sfdc.workingFin))
WHERE TRUE
```

Comment: please follow [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can actually help you. sample of input and expected result is a must if you really expect us to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE sfdc.workingFin wf
    SET Notes = (SELECT STRING_AGG(string_field_0) 
                 FROM sfdc.tasks t 
                 WHERE t.string_field_0 LIKE wf.Email
                )
    WHERE true;
```

Comment: Got an error for the two from's and then another for a missing Where True at the bottom, but ended up with the same error as before.

Comment: it should be t.string_field_0 = wf.Email